# How to move GoogleMap camera to display completly a long marker InfoWindow when opened?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, infowindow

When using GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter to display a custom dialog, if the dialog has too much text, when it's openned, the map doesn't leave to see all the dialog text.

Is there an automatic way to move the googlemap camera to display completely the InfoWindow of the marker?

Maybe calculating the marker InfoWindow size and doing some tricks for move the camera a little?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this but make sure your infoWindow dialog is scrollable so you can see the all content of dialog

Comment: Please, can you post your solution with code example?